# Count largest negative series in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I am looking for a series of negative/positive numbers. Let's say that I have a table with two columns: order_time and win, where order_time is a date and win is +1 or -1. I would like to find the greatest series of negative values in column "win". I know how to do it in Python but I would like to do it in postgres and not going to the other environments.

Example

```
      order_time     wins
2020-01-02 17:12:19    0
2020-01-02 17:12:19    0
2020-01-02 21:02:15    1
2020-01-03 02:40:56    1
2020-01-03 10:38:39    0
2020-01-03 10:38:44    0
2020-01-03 10:38:44    1
2020-01-03 10:38:44    0
2020-01-03 10:58:32    1
2020-01-03 11:18:13    1
2020-01-03 11:18:35    1
```

output

```
      order_time     wins   s
2020-01-02 17:12:19    0    1
2020-01-02 17:12:19    0    2
2020-01-02 21:02:15    1    1
2020-01-03 02:40:56    1    2
2020-01-03 10:38:39    0    1
2020-01-03 10:38:44    0    2
2020-01-03 10:38:44    1    1
2020-01-03 10:38:44    0    1
2020-01-03 10:58:32    1    1
2020-01-03 11:18:13    1    2
2020-01-03 11:18:35    1    3
```

and then I would find max of column s

Comment: provide sample data with your desired output

Comment: Do you mean consecutive positive or negative numbers? Does the date is important or not?

Comment: Your example doesn't have negative numbers. Did you mean `0` instead of `-1`?

Comment: Try to write something using the [LAG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)- function.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name - yes, you are right, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I do not understant clearly what you need. You can mainly use MAX(...) over (partition by ...) or LEAD or LAG just to find the output. Give more desired expected output if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Detect when wins changes, then use change flag to create groups. Number rows in each group and take the max row number.

```sql
with t (order_time,     wins) as (values
(timestamp '2020-01-02 17:12:19',    0),
(timestamp '2020-01-02 17:12:19',    0),
(timestamp '2020-01-02 21:02:15',    1),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 02:40:56',    1),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 10:38:39',    0),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 10:38:44',    0),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 10:38:44',    1),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 10:38:44',    0),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 10:58:32',    1),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 11:18:13',    1),
(timestamp '2020-01-03 11:18:35',    1)
), ch as (
  select t.*
       , case coalesce(wins != lag(wins) over (order by order_time), true) 
           when true then 1
           else 0
         end as wins_changed
  from t
), groups as (
  select ch.*
       , sum(wins_changed) over (order by order_time) as grp
  from ch
), counts as (
  select order_time
       , wins
       , row_number() over (partition by grp order by order_time) rn
  from groups
)
select max(rn) from counts;
```

Note your example is unclear at row triplet `2020-01-03 10:38:44`. How can the query recognize the `win=1` value is the one in the middle? For this reason, my query returns 3 also for this row triplet. You can avoid it either by more precising `order_time` (to millisecond) or adding another `order by` criterion.

Db fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=68e2e6fb634429b0fa47c8c69fb2e7f6).

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Probably the simplest approach to identify the "islands" of adjacent values is the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by wins, seqnum - seqnum_1 order by order_time) as s
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by order_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by wins order by order_time) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can actually get the longest streak without a subquery:

```
select count(*) over (partition by wins, seqnum - seqnum_1 order by order_time) as s
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by order_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by wins order by order_time) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t
order by s desc
limit 1;
```

If you want the longest series of losses (or wins), just add `where wins = <whatever>` to the outer query.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a8a67571ab5873b57610690756707709) is a db<>fiddle.